# Comparing two columns in different MS access tables and displaying results in a data table using c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access, datagridview

I am reasonably new to C# and am working on a c# windows application project which scans the registry on a windows computer and displays the results (Display_Name and publisher). These results are then stored in a table 'Scan_Results' in MS Access using a oledbconnection.

I also have a form which records the license details (Name, license key). These details are however, manually entered. These details are then recorded in the table 'Licenses' within the same database as 'Scan_Results.

I would like to compare the 'Name' column in the 'license' table i.e Office, with the 'Display_Name' in 'Scan_Results'.

I want the records that do not match to be displayed in a datatable/datagridview. I would also like those that do match to be displayed in a seperate datatable/datagridview.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you have any questions please let me know and I will try my best to answer.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: currently i have two datagridviews which read the data from each table it the database; but other than that nothing. I am unsure how to go about starting it. Would you have any advice on what to look at?

Comment: You probably want to figure out how to construct the queries in order to display what you want, which will probably involve using a View. Are you versed in SQL?

Comment: no, i'm unfortunately not versed in SQL. I will look into views and see if i can progress any further

Comment: You'd want to do an inner join on `Scan_Results.Display_Name and License.Name` for the first query. For the second, you could do a couple things... you could either do an outer join between the two tables on the fields I just mentioned and if `License.Name` is null, you know there wasn't a match. Similarly, if your tables have proper unique keys (a Primary Key for example), you could just select the records for all keys that don't exist in the first query.

Comment: In the Display_name the data is displayed as 'Microsoft Office Publisher MUI (English) 2010' for example, where as in license details it is listed just as Office. Will an inner join still match the results even though they aren't an exact match? Thanks.

Comment: No, it has to be an exact match. What are your requirements? Do you want anything where License.Name is contained within Scan_Results.Display_Name to be a match?

Comment: Yes I want to return results where License.Name is contained within Scan_Results.Display_Name

Comment: A quick google search for "access contains in join" will give you what you're looking for